Double disk bundle
Double disk bundle: A smooth, closed manifold
$M \cong  DB^{-} \cup_L DB^{+}$
where
· $B^{±}, L$ smooth, closed manifolds
· $D^{l± +1} → DB^{±} → B^{±}$ smooth disk bundles such that
$S^{l±} → L \cong ∂DB^{−} \cong  ∂DB^{+} → B^{±}$ is sphere bundle.
In the above Double disk bundle, I do not understand what is base space and fibre of a double disk bundle are.
Please give some ideas to understand.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The basic idea is that you have a manifold $L$ which fibers in two different ways as a sphere bundle, over two different base spaces $B_\pm$. So you have
two locally trivial fibrations
$$
S_\pm\to L\xrightarrow{p_\pm} B_\pm.
$$
Associated to each of these fibrations is its mapping cylinder $M_{p_\pm}$, which is a disk bundle (the cone over a a sphere is a disk),
$$
D_\pm\to M_{p_\pm}\xrightarrow{r_\pm} B_\pm.
$$
The disk bundle maps $r_\pm$ are deformation retractions (since they are
obtained from the mapping cylinders of $p_\pm$) and we have inclusion maps
$i_\pm:L\to M_{p_\pm}$. Note that $M_{p_\pm}$ are manifolds with boundary $L$. We may therefore glue $M_{p_+}$ and $M_{p_-}$ along $L$. The resulting manifold
$M=M_{p_-}\cup_L M_{p_+}$ is
called the double mapping cylinder. It may or may not be a sphere, depending on $p_+$ and $p_-$
A good example is the case where $L$ is the flag manifold of $\mathbb C^3$,
which is (real) 6-dimensional and fibers in the obvious way over $\mathbb CP^2$
(by mapping a flag $(E\subseteq F)$ to the one-dimensional subspace $E$),
and which fibers in a different way over $\mathbb CP^2$ by mapping $(E\subseteq F)$ to the one-dimensional subspace $F^\perp$.
In this case one can show that $M\cong \mathbb S^7$, for example by representing flags as traceless hermitian $3\times3$-matrices of norm $1$.
